# Splunk associate: specific Reference_Value of a Reference_Key is not being returned in the restul

Tags: correlation, splunk

I'm trying to correlate two variables X_1, X_2, each is a binomial variable.

I'm running this command: `| associate supcnt=1 improv=0 supfreq=0` on my query results, but for Reference_Key=X_1, only one of the possible two Reference_Values is being displayed. I'm pretty sure I've verified that the support count of both X_1=x_a and X_1=x_b are greater than 1, x_a and x_b being the only two possible values of X_1.

Why would it not display the result for one of the reference values?